# Saved Photos album name without Location Services permission

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, assetslibrary

I'd like to a get the name of the Saved Photos album programmatically. The value changes based on locale and whether or not the device has a camera (Camera Roll vs. Saved Photos), so hard-coding is not preferable.

I am aware that I can use AssetsLibrary to get the album name, like so:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos 
                       usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                   NSLog(@"%@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);
                       }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {}];
```

However, doing so requires that the user authorize access to Location Services, which is unacceptable for my scenario.

Any other means of gettings this album name without requiring permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only by using AssestsLibrary, which requires that the users grants access to location services. I suggest you fill a bug report/enhancement request at radar.apple.com.

Cheers,

Hendrik